# Java android save HTML from website

Tags: java, android

#### In java this is what I would use to download the html:

```
   static   public  String savePage(final String URL) throws IOException {
    String line = "", all = "";
    java.net.URL myUrl = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL(URL);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream()));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            all += line;

        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    return all;
}
```

The HTML I get by using this code in normal java is exactly what I need. However when I try using this code in Android Java (Android studio) the resulting HTML is incomplete and is not what I need. All I want is the HTML to be exactly how it is on the actual link.

#### This is what the HTML looks like when I download it in Android Java:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-GB">  <head id="head">    <style
name="www-roboto">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/W4wDsBUluyw0tK3tykhXEXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/QHD8zigcbDB8aPfIoaupKOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUSZ2oysoEQEeKwjgmXLRnTc.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0SwlidHJgAgmTjOEEzwu1L8.ttf)format('truetype');}</style><script
name="www-roboto">if (document.fonts && document.fonts.load) {document.fonts.load("400 10pt Roboto", "E");document.fonts.load("500 10pt Roboto", "E");}</script>      <script>var ytcsi = {gt: function(n) {n = (n || '') + 'data_';return ytcsi[n] || (ytcsi[n] = {tick: {},span: {},info: {}});},tick: function(l, t, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).tick[l] = t || +new Date();},span: function(l, s, e, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).span[l] = (e ? e : +new Date()) - ytcsi.gt(n).tick[s];},setSpan: function(l, s, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).span[l]
= s;},info: function(k, v, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).info[k] = v;},setStart: function(s, t, n) {ytcsi.info('yt_sts', s, n);ytcsi.tick('_start', t, n);}};(function(w, d) {ytcsi.perf = w.performance || w.mozPerformance ||w.msPerformance || w.webkitPerformance;ytcsi.setStart('dhs', ytcsi.perf ? ytcsi.perf.timing.responseStart : null);var isPrerender = (d.visibilityState || d.webkitVisibilityState) == 'prerender';var vName = d.webkitVisibilityState ? 'webkitvisibilitychange' : 'visibilitychange';if (isPrerender) {ytcsi.info('prerender', 1);var startTick = function() {ytcsi.setStart('dhs');d.removeEventListener(vName, startTick);};d.addEventListener(vName, startTick, false);}if (d.addEventListener) {d.addEventListener(vName, function() {ytcsi.tick('vc');}, false);}})(window, document);</script>    <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'initpb');}</script>    <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'blz_watch_ads');}</script>    <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'blz_home_ads');}</script>    <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'blz_search_ads');}</script>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=medium-dpi">  <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/favicon-vflz7uhzw.ico" type="image/x-icon">  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/favicon-vflz7uhzw.ico" type="image/x-icon">   <title>YouTube</title>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/mobile-nirvana-tablet-mangled-vflylHmeV.css" id="page_css">  </head>  <body id="body" class="atom fusion-tn">       <script>      var original_url = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(document.location.href))); var iframe_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fnext%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fm.youtube.com%252Fsignin_passive%253Foriginal_url%253DORIGINAL_URL_PLACE_HOLDER%26hl%3Den-GB%26feature%3Dmobile_passive%26app%3Dm%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue&amp;hl=en-GB&amp;passive=true&amp;service=youtube&amp;uilel=3'.replace('ORIGINAL_URL_PLACE_HOLDER', original_url);      document.write('<iframe src=\"' + iframe_url + '\" style=\"width:0;height:0;margin:0;border-width:0;padding:0;position:absolute;\"></iframe>'); </script>  <div id="player"></div>  <div id="guide-layout-container">  <div id="guide-container"></div>    <div id="content-container">      <div id="content"></div>    </div>    <div id="guide-overlay"></div>   <div id="lightbox"></div>    <div id="toast"></div>    <div id="content-overlay"></div>  </div>  <div id="_yt_orientation_de
```

#### This HTML is nothing like the website, Im trying to download it from. Ive tried a lot of different methods for downloading html from websites and all give me incomplete and random HTML like this.

I have tried to encode the URL and used libraries that I can use to download HTML but still no luck.

An explanation to this and a maybe even code that would do what I want would be greatly appreciated. Android java is new to me so lots of details would help me understand better.

Thank you

Comment: Look at `http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/` for an easy way to download a html page

Comment: looks like the url provides a mobile HTML version, you confirm it?

Comment: You are downloading a dynamic webpage. The Javascript is not executed when you download the URL, i.e. The HTML will not contain what you want

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I have tried jsoup, It gave me the same incomplete HTML.

Comment: You should load the page in a `WebView` and then work with the resulting HTML

Comment: Are you trying to scrape YouTube? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Have to tried other websites? There are YouTube APIs if you just want YouTube data

Comment: @PeteHouston I would want the URL to provide the standard version of the website not the mobile version

Comment: @cricket_007 That makes sense, how would I go about activating the javascript and downloading the html? I didnt have to do that in normal java.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I can load the link in WebView but how would I go about saving that HTML?

Comment: In order for the site to think you are not accessing the site from a mobile device, you need to set the User Agent header in your savePage code

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I'm trying to scrape the links and titles from Youtube, API's seem to complicated to me because I'm new to Java, is there any API's you know that would do what I want?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you so much! It worked

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do... APIs beat manual Web parsing any day, IMO. They are intimidating at times, but the reason you use APIs is because they are (hopefully)  well documented, explanatory, and filled with examples. [Here is YouTube's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, if you want to site to think you are not communicating with it from a mobile device, you need to set the User-Agent in the network request.